# CSS background images not showing on the ipad

Tags: css

I'm totally confused and wondering whether i'm just missing something simple, but i am unable to display a background image on an ipad or within the ipad simulator.

As a test i put together the following simple page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img src="content_box_black_background.png" />
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 500px; background:url(content_box_black_background.png);">
    </div>
</body></html>
```

As a test I am also outputting the image directly above the div block. In chrome they both appear but in the ipad simulator neither do. Any ideas?

Comment: If they both appear in chrome, and neither appear in the simulator, then I don't suspect that you trying to use it as a "background" image has anything to do with your problem. It sounds like the simulator is not picking up the path to the image.

Comment: Look right to me. I would try a few things though, maybe the simulator is buggy: url('content_box_black_background.png'); or url('./content_box_black_background.png');

Comment: What iPad simulator ? Could you put in a link to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tests these, but I have a few ideas you should test:

1) How are the files placed on a "local drive" of an iPad? you don't have any HTTP, so I assume you have the image on the "harddrive" (RAM) - try to open the file directly in the browser, does it show/download?

2) Try to add: "display:block;" to your CSS rendering. Might do the trick

3) The IMG tag, try adding width and height, does it change anything?

4) What type of PNG file are you using? 8-bit or 24-bit?

5) What happens if you use a GIF or JPG instead?

6) when using background images. Try using the long format for the attributes. "background-image:url(image.jpg);".

7) Also try adding a `<!DOCTYPE html>` so the browser goes into HTML5 mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Often it takes a list of simple checks to help sort things out. I am unable to try each of the suggestions out yet, but i am sure it will be one of those (most likely the PNG format i have used on a particular graphic). Thanks for your input.

Comment: RAM is system memory, whereas harddisks are for file storage - they're entirely unrelated in different levels.

Comment: @Christian - I posted "harddrive" as a "similarity". I know what the difference between Flash RAM, RAM, Harddrives etc. are. No need to vote my answer down because I compare the internal storage with a harddrive. Thats what most people are used to from normal computers. I got my first computer back in 1987, so please understand it was meant as a similarity for the sacke of comparison and explanation.

Answer (score 27):

It could be related to the dimensions of the image. The [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15) mentions that the maximum size for GIF, PNG and TIFF images is 3 megapixels (3 * 1024 * 1024). I ran into a similar issue displaying a menu based on CSS sprites. I had to shrink the rather large image (3000x1500) before any of the sprites would display on the iPad.

Comment: this solved a problem I was having with my ipad site - thanks a lot :)

Comment: I had the same issue. If you are using a sprite, make sure its' width and height are as minimal as possible. My sprite size was only about 130k and still the iPad 2 didn't show it because the width was 4000 pixels.

Answer (score 3):

IPAD doesn't like `cover` in background shorthand. 
If you are using cover do it on a new line

```
   -webkit-background-size: cover; 
   -moz-background-size: cover; 
   -o-background-size: cover; 
     background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have valid CSS! http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

I've run into this issue before and validating/fixing my CSS fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

In some mobile theme setting you will find "shrink large images within posts or pages to fit on smaller screens. "
check for enable/disable it.
And disable it..

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

always put quotes around your url and either the full `url("http://example.com/folder/file.htm")` or at least the slash `url("/file.htm")`

Comment: if there is no spaces, the quotes are NOT needed. Sorry.

Comment: Quotes are totally unnecesasry if there are no spaces, and same applies to full url specifying, why'd you actually want that? CSS reads url's realtive to it's own path. I.E. If your *.css* sits inside `<site root>/styles` and images inside `<site root>/styles/images` you'd use url in CSS like `url(images/<image>.extension)` and it would work perfectly!

Comment: or you could just not be a troll.

Comment: @isildur4: no, I wouldn't call it "good habit", as you could forget one of the quotes and get even more trouble. Less is more.

Comment: i c u trohling
i b hateeng
gtfo my post u newb

Comment: I totally agree. Paths dont need to be absolute nor do they need to include quotes. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Surely quotes are better practice because the image may have a name like: "/myimage(not really an image).jpg" or /beach_pics).jpg etc